# JDBC SqlParameterValue - determine SQL Type of parameter

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm working in Java and trying to determine something like so:

I have a SqlParameterSource with an array named "ids" in it. I need to determine what type these ids are in, for example numeric or varchar. I specify that earlier in the code with for example:

```
return con.createArrayOf("varchar")
```

or

```
return con.createArrayOf("numeric")
```

I have tried this:

```
 if (parametersource.getSqlType("ids") == something) {
// do something
}
 else {
//do something else
}
```

I can't figure out how to do this. getSqlType seems to return an int but I don't know what to compare it to to get the correct comparison.
There is another method named getTypeName but I don't get how this works.

Comment: JDBC in itself doesn't have anything called "SqlParameterSource", so there seems to be some information missing from your question.

Comment: What is this `SqlParameterSource` thing? If your JDBC driver supports it, you can use `PreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#getParameterMetaData--

Comment: In pure JDBC, I would use `ResultSetMetaData` but you seems to use [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/SqlParameterSource.html) (if so, add the tag to your question)

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's Spring SqlParameterSource. :) I forgot to say that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with:

```
parameterSource.getValue("objtype").toString();
```

Fetches the value from "objtype" which I set in my ParameterSource alongside my array to make my end goal easier.

Thanks friends, I love you all. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about Spring SqlParameterSource,try `parametersource.getTypeName("ids")`which is inherited from [AbstractSqlParameterSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/AbstractSqlParameterSource.html)